# WPF binding label content with class parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've read a bunch of tutorials on the net, docs on MSDN and answers here but I still don't understand a binding in WPF. I have my own C# class like this

```
namespace Organizer
```

{

```
public class UIDate
{
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private String dateStr;

    public UIDate()
    {
        DateTime actualDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        year = actualDateTime.Year;
        month = actualDateTime.Month;
        dateStr = Convert.ToString(Year);
    }

    public int Year
    {
        get { return year; }
        set { year = value; }
    }

    public int Month
    {
        get { return month; }
        set { month = value; }
    }

    public String DateStr
    {
        get { return dateStr; }
        set { dateStr = value; }
    }
}
```

}

and i want to bind the property DateStr with label content here

```
<Window x:Class="Organizer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" WindowState="Normal">
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button MinWidth="25" MaxHeight="25" Margin="8"/>
        <Button MinWidth="15" MaxHeight="15" Margin="5"/>
        <Label Name="UIDateYM" Content="{Binding Path=UIDate.DateStr, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0, 8"/>
```

The rest of XAML is unrelated, I believe.

And the xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Organizer;

namespace Organizer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logika interakcji dla klasy MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();
            UIDate uiDate = new UIDate();
            this.DataContext = uiDate;
        }
    }
}
```

When application runs there's no txt in label. Content is empty.
I checked my uiDate object and it works. Property and it's field has a right value, as I wanted. How to bind them? What did i missed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you have to set a data context (ok)= -> (you have done that, if you use MVVM there are more elegant ways but thats fine)

   2. you have set a binding in xaml but you are binding to class name UIDate.DateStr

if you set the data context to an element. all child nodes will have the same data context -> as long as you didn't changed it. (you set it to window / this, so the label as a child has also the same data context)

keep in mind, your DataContext is already set, you can directly access the properties in it.

change:

```
{Binding Path=UIDate.DateStr, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

to:

```
{Binding Path=DateStr}
```

the updatesourcetrigger here is not required. Bec. triggers are here to inform the bounded object that something changed. (only in this direction).

In your case your, the label is not an input control and has only to show the value. means the control doesn't need to inform your bound object that something changed.

Next Point:
If you are not going change the value in your Object. You can keep your code as it is.
Bec. if you set an object (in your case you set the data context) all binding which reference this object are getting updated. So the initial value is set.

But if you change a value when the object is already bound, you need to notify the Control. You should look for the interface INotifyPropertyChanged ...

greets hope its clear now

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand how binding works. Was sure thate UpdateSourceTrigger will do it but it works in opposite direction. 
I think i have to get familiar with MVVM pattern.

Comment: You are welcome. After years of experience with wpf and using it in larger business applications, i recommend using the MVVM pattern, its a littlebit more initial work, but its definitly worth it in 90% of the cases.